# Heroku login the system cannot find the path specified

Tags: node.js, heroku, command-line-interface

I have a problems using Heroku CLI.
1. I installed Heroku CLI on Winows 10 with all environment variables. 
But have this message : "Heroku login the system cannot find the path specified".
What to do to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you are still looking for a solution but I encountered with the same problem today and solved it by doing:

This error was caused by some kind of bug in heroku which prompts uploading heroku.

Everytime I type heroku in the command line. So, I just uninstall and installed the heroku again. However, it kept throwing same error when i type anything start with heroku

The solution was to delete heroku files from:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\heroku\cli\bin` (`%LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku\cli\bin`)

Then, when i started it again and it worked smoothly

Comment: The issue is still present in the binaries for Windows. Your solution works, thanks !